# nmap cannot check ipv6 global ip on localhost

Tags: networking, ipv6, nmap

If I use nmap like this (the AAA record of the website redirects to this machine) :

```
nmap -6 -sV mywebsite.com
```

nmap seems to access all ports like it was a localhost scan. However if I do :

```
nmap -4 -sV mywebsite.com
```

Here I only have public ports available.
If I try to access ipv6 ports via another machine, ports are closed.

Why nmap seems to do a localhost scan?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that an internet IPv6 scan is the same as a localhost scan,
is because with IPv6 your computer is directly exposed to the internet.

With IPv4, the router used
[Network address translation (NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation),
so you connect to the router, rather than the computer, which does
the necessary message translation. You do not have direct connection
to the computer.

With IPv6, you have point-to-point connection, so your computer
can directly connect to itself.

Note that not all routers permit loopback connections from the local
network and back, but your router evidently supports it.

Comment: And is it possible to bypass it and therefore act as a public ip scanning from the same computer?

Comment: You may isolate your local ports from the internet via firewall, either yours or in the router. I find it strange that the firewall of your router doesn't protect you against such access.

Comment: I opened all my ports for this device on ipv4 and ipv6 so it can be accessed as it is a server and there is only my firewall that I have control of. However, I don't know how to make this scan act as a outside scan and make firewall rules apply (that works from another device). But ports are normally blocked by my firewall.